# Solaris - How to see if Bash is installed

Tags: bash, solaris, sunos

never touched Solaris before is there an easy command to see if Bash is installed?

Probably a silly question, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying this but have you tried typing "bash" at the command prompt?

Comment: Yes. Says not found, but does that mean it's not installed?

Comment: It could be that it's not installed or could be that you've not got the path set, try /usr/bin/bash .

Comment: Directory is not there, guessing it not installed

Comment: And one final thing to try:
pkginfo|grep -i bash

Answer (score 2):

To check if bash package is installed try this command (verified on Solaris 10):

```
pkginfo -l SUNWbash
```

It may be also installed from 3rd-party software repository, then, try:

```
pkginfo | grep -i bash
```

Comment: On Solaris 11 & later, instead run `pkg info shell/bash`.

Comment: On Solaris 10 & before, you can use `grep` to look into `/var/sadm/install/contents`, that file lists all the files installed in packages. `grep bin/bash /var/sadm/install/contents`

Answer (score 1):

If bash is installed the follwing will state which version you have, otherwise thorw an error

```
/usr/bin/bash --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that can bash can also be compiled from the source by a regular user account and run from a home directory. Try `find / -name '*bash*'` or so.

Answer (score 0):

The locate command simply searches a database of files on the system.  My hack on my SUNOS uses the find command to create a text database and then just greps that datebase for future file hunts.  Note that creating the text database (about 200 Mbytes) on my SUNOS takes a long time.   The grep only takes a few seconds per search.

`find / > ~/locate_db`

`grep bin/bash ~/locate_db`